# xslt external-graphic source from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

is there any way to use xml tag instead of writing complete path in

```
<External-Graphics src="filepath" />
```

i want to use an xml tag instead of file path without declaring a variable like

```
<block paddint-bottom="0pt">
     <xsl:variable name="imagepath">
       <xsl:value-of select="xmlTagName/innertag"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>
   <external-graphic src="url({$imagepath})" text-align="center" />
 </block>
```

should be like

```
<external-graphic src="xml tag name" text-align="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, yes you can put the XPath directly in the [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) (`{}`).

Something like:

```
<block paddint-bottom="0pt">
  <external-graphic src="url({xmlTagName/innertag})" text-align="center" />
</block>
```